# How to tell if Vue-Router navigation hook was triggered by "push"?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I need to perform a certain action whenever a call to router.push is triggered.

I'm trying to use Vue-Router's navigation guards for this, but there is no way to tell, inside of its callback, what method (go/push/back/replace) triggered it.

```
router.beforeResolve((to, from) => {
      // Do something only if this was triggered by "push"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just hook vue-router push/back/replace function before Vue.use(vue-router),
then get navigation type by call
`this.$router.customNaviType;`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'


const routerPush = Router.prototype.push;
// rewrite push
Router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  this.customNaviType = "push";
  return routerPush.call(this, location).catch(error => error)
}

const routerBack = Router.prototype.back;  
// rewrite back
Router.prototype.back = function back() {
  this.customNaviType = "back";
  return routerBack.call(this);
}

const routerReplace = Router.prototype.replace;  
// rewrite replace
Router.prototype.replace = function replace(location) {
  this.customNaviType = "replace";
  return routerReplace.call(this, location).catch(error => error)
}


Vue.use(Router)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

By my understanding, only push method will increase the history.length by one.

Maybe use a global variable to keep check `window.history.length`. If it increase, then you can trigger your `push` event.

For example:

```js
router.beforeResolve((to, from) => {
  if (window.history.length > window.last_history_length) {
    trigger_your_push_event();
  }
  window.last_history_length = window.history.length;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can not be catched by navigation guards directly:
[image]

**But**,

using the state of your app you can have a better idea which operation is done. You can do it by saving the current and your last route to your state using the guard `afterEach`. Once you know them, you can compare them with `from` and `to` parameters in e.g. `beforeEach` to get know whether it is a push or back. You can probably add more metadata to your routes so you get know more about your routes to decide whether it is replaced by some kind of other type route:

[image]